# How to develop android application using ARCore in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore, android-augmented-reality

Im new in developing ARCore application. Im trying to develop but only 3D object appear after scan surface. I want UI button works and have animation when I click the button. Anyone can help me and have a tutorial step by step?

Answer (score 1):

For UIButton play animation:

```
public GameObject your3dGameObject
public void OnButtonClick()
{
     your3dGameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("animationName");
}
```

And you can set the transform of canvas as a child of the 3DGameObject then the UIButton will appear/disappear with surface detecting.

[image]